E: Unsupported file ./zoom_amd64.deb given on commandline
It's been a while since I've been trying to install the latest version of Zoom on my laptop. Apparently, I'm doing everything right, but then once I type the command, I get this reply. E: Unsupported file ./zoom_amd64.deb given on commandline
I'd appreciate it if someone could help me. Mine is a Lenovo, I have a Linux Debian. Thanks.

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

A .deb file is an installer file (a package) created for Debian and Debian based distros.
You need to first tell the package manager apt or dpkg to install this package with
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb  or
sudo dkpg -i ./zoom_amd64.deb
